# Link error when attempting to measure time in kernel using do_gettimeofday()

Tags: time, linux-kernel, linker-errors

I'm attempting to time some functions calls made by a driver. So I called `do_gettimeofday` to get the `struct timeval` of the time. It compiles, but the linker complains thusly:

```
drivers/built-in.o: In function `SPC_TIMING_add':
hid-quirks.c:(.text+0x31354): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
hid-quirks.c:(.text+0x31384): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
hid-quirks.c:(.text+0x31398): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dadd'
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Error 1
```

I tried reading the value of `xtime` directly, and got the same result.

Obviously, there's some kind of mistake in the link-order, but since I'm not sure where `__aeabi_i2d` and `__aeabi_dadd` come from, I don't know what makefile to edit.

**UPDATE**: Turns out that "aeabi" means "Embedded Application Binary Interface" (EABI) for the ARM Architecture. The `dadd` instruction is double-precision addition, and `i2d` is integer-to-double conversion (according to [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0043c/IHI0043C_rtabi.pdf)). I guess this means that my problem isn't simply linking, but of convincing the compiler to use the right instruction, or a surrogate instruction (which seems to be what is being done in `arch/arm/lib/lib1funcs.S`).

**UPDATE**: According to a Google search, `__aeabi_dadd` is often aliased to be `__adddf3`, and `__aeabi_i2d` is aliased to `__floatsidf`.

**UPDATE**: After looking closely at the actual compiler's output, it turns out that the error has nothing to do with `do_gettimeofday`. It was merely that commenting-out the call to `do_gettimeofday` allowed the compiler's optimizer to remove references to a function that was performing double-precision floating point operations. Once that function was not longer being called, the error wouldn't appear. And that's why I thought it was being caused by `do_gettimeofday`.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do floating point arithmetic, which the compiler is trying to emulate, but then failing to find the emulation routines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in the kernel you probably shouldn't be using `do_gettimeofday()`.

I think the right way to do it is using the `ktime` family of functions, eg:

```
ktime_t start, end, delta;

start = ktime_get();
...
end = ktime_get();

delta = ktime_sub(end, start);
```

There are then a bunch of conversion routines in `ktime.h` for turning `delta` into milli/nano/etc seconds.

Comment: I ended up calling `getnstimeofday()` because that was recommended instead of `do_gettimeofday()`. However, looking at the code in `kernel/time/timekeeping.c` indicates that this isn't much different than `get_ktime()`, except for the way the value is returned.

Comment: I'm awarding you the answer because of your comment to the question. As it turned out, the question itself was invalid. The problem wasn't to do with measuring time at all, and really was a problem with performing (or emulating) floating-point math.

Comment: Thanks.

I still think you should be using `ktime_get()`, especially if you're doing arithmetic on the result. Also note that `getnstimeofday()` returns wall clock time, which may go backward, vs monotonic time which will not.